# Parameter in function declaration having 2D array

Tags: c++, c, function-declaration

For functions:

```
void fn1(int M[size][size],int n,int m){
    ....... 
}
```

OR

```
 void fn1(int M[][size],int n,int m){ 
    .......
 }
```

is the declaration of function 
What should be the function declaration at the beginning?

The declaration :

```
void fn1(int **M,int n,int m);
```

showing error due to mismatch in int **M and int M[][].

Then what should be the proper form?

Comment: Both are correct , as per , but in first `2-d` arrays size if fixed , i.e `size x size` .

Comment: Either can work; they're equivalent as `size` must be a constant, I think.  If you want the array to be of size m by n then you must use `void fn1(int m, int n, int M[m][n])` in C99 or later; you don't get the choice to do this in C89/C90.  Note that the array size parameters must appear before the array itself.

Comment: @ameyCU: although the size of the second dimension is fixed at `size`, the size of the first dimension could be anything using either notation; the compiler won't enforce any bounds checking and passing and using a bigger (or smaller) array won't cause any trouble as long as you stay within the bounds of the actual array that is passed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Yes , I agree Sir ,in  that comment I referred to array in first definition of function .

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ohh ,wait . So if `size` is `10` and I pass it an array of `int m[11][11]` it would be fine in first definition?

Comment: Yup, as long as you don't use the array elements that aren't part of the actual array parameter.

Comment: @all I edited the post.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir , I was talking about this definition `void fn1(int M[size][size],int n,int m)` where if I define `size=10` , and pass it an array of `m[11][11]` , then compiler generates an error . In this context was ,my first comment about .

Comment: A good C++-ish declaration would be `void fn1(Matrix<int, size, size>& matrix, int n, int m)`, with `Matrix` being a user-defined template class.